# Please make the close dialog on Teams draggable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, stack-overflow-for-teams, popup

Recently, we've got the ability to close questions as off-topic in Teams. This is neat, but when trying it out, I noticed the close dialog is not draggable. On public Q&A sites, the dialog has a title "Why should this question be closed?" which you can use to drag it across the screen. This is useful if you want to do a final check if the question is really close-worthy, if you're still in doubt about the reason to use, or the original to use as a duplicate. The Teams dialog doesn't have a title, the easiest way is probably just to add it.

[image]

Comment: Is the whitespace above “duplicate of…” really not draggable? I’ve seen dialogs with a blank “title” being draggable.

Comment: It might depend on the browser, but on mine (Firefox, macOS), it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch! The lack of draggability was caused by the headline of the dialog box not being present. Fixed that, now it's all draggable again!

[image]